# How we can add javascript in joomla article?

Tags: joomla1.5

I have to convert an HTML site into joomla.Some Content of the site contain javascript which is not supported by the joomla article. so please tell me how can i do.

Comment: I have got it...Dont get panic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just switch to jce editor in joomla